# Use hyperlink in a TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Code written below

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" Width="450"
    Text="Posted In" Foreground="Red"
    TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Run Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding CategoryName}"></Run>
    <Run Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding CreatedOn}"></Run>
    <LineBreak/>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run
        Foreground="Black"
        FontSize="24"
        Text="{Binding ArticleDescription}"></Run>
    <LineBreak/>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run Foreground="Red" Text="Posted By"></Run>
    <Run Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding CreatedBy}"></Run>
    <Hyperlink Foreground="Red">sadas</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Basically I used this code if I use hyperlink it crashes the application. If I don't use the hyperlink, the application works totally fine. How can I use a hyperlink in a textblock?

**Error message:**

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use RichtextBox ether then textbox

```
<RichTextBox TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="John Doe" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="503 (Building DS 126)" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="tel.:  +30 210-1234567" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink_OnClick">e-mail:   johndoe@uni.gr</Hyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set NavigateUri property in HyperLink Class (i.e. HyperLink control). For more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i try both link but app crash

Comment: Linking a solution is great. Showing what needs to be done in the answer itself is even better. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

here is sample code

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="txtSource"  Text="abc"  Tap="LinkClicked" />
```

and in code behind LinkClicked event put this

```
  private void LinkClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {


                        string url = "http://google.com";
                        WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
                        wbt.Uri = new Uri(url);
                        wbt.Show();
        }
```

hope this is what you where looking for

Comment: did you got the solution? @Radhika Sharma